# Top menu bar disappeared on all applications in Linux Mint 14 XFCE

Tags: linux, linux-mint

The top menu bar disappeared off of all of my applications in Linux Mint 14 XFCE. You can still see the menu item, like "File", "Edit", etc. However, the outline around the window is gone and the is no X to close windows. You can drag, but you can't minimize or maximize. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: ive seen that happen in older releases... not recently tho.  I guess the bug is still around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
xfwm4
xfwm4 --replace
```

Did the trick for me. Source: http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=110&t=71858